# How to upgrade electron to latest version?

Tags: javascript, electron

Whats the best way to upgrade to the latest version of electron?
Should I be concerned about any problems caused by upgrading?

I’m playing around with “electron”: “^1.7.9”, and “react”: “^16.1.1”, on linux.
I’m using yarn, not npm;

The app I’m playing around with has never been ejected, so the assumed config is intact.

The codebase I'm using is here:
https://github.com/csepulv/electron-with-create-react-app

Comment: since you have your code on github you should be fine with just upgrading and seeing what breaks. Then when you're sure its working again, you commit the changes along side the version bump. Also see: https://www.christianengvall.se/update-to-latest-electron-version/

However since the latest version is 4 marjor version later than your version, you might just want to start over.

Comment: btw, why are you playing around with a 2 year old version?

Comment: I wanted to find the cleanest electron/react boilerplate, something not too complicated, as I'm trying to learn the basics of electron and react. This one fit the bill, with one exception, it was using very old versions.

Comment: I tried to upgrade using "    "yarn global upgrade --latest", all ran with no errors, but nothing was upgraded. However electron -v says 1.8.8, but package.json says 1.7.9

Comment: OK I got it upgraded by changing  “electron”: “^1.7.9” to  “electron”: “@”, in the package.json file. And then ran "yarn install", yarn asked me to pick a version, and gave me a list to pick from... I chose 5.0.2. then yarn build and all works fine...... :-)

Answer (score 6):

To upgrade the node library to the latest version and for electron in this instance you should use:

```
npm install electron@latest
```

Answer (score 1):

What if electron forge is not compatible with node js?
You need to update everything with the latest version.

```
## update electron

# 1. Check node version or if use nvm auto script ->  nvm ls
node -v

# 2. clean cache 
npm cache clean -f


# 3. Download and install from here https://nodejs.org/en/download/


# 4. install node version n Latest LTS Version: 16.15.0 (includes npm 8.5.5)  
# Install n globally 
# or --> npm install -g npm stable
npm install -g n latest

# 5
npm install -g npm 
 
# 6 Then update node or npm install -g n
npm install -g node

# 7 update node and npm in one command o
npm install -g npm@latest
 
# 7. Update electron or 
# https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/updates#:~:text=The%20easiest%20way%20to%20use,with%20update.electronjs.org.&text=By%20default%2C%20this%20module%20will,be%20downloaded%20in%20the%20background.
npm install electron@latest
npm install update-electron-app

# 8. check node version and electron version

# 9. Restart computer

## end update electron
```